# Sequences $(f_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ that converge in $d_{l^{\infty}}$ but not in $d_{l^{1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

We are working in $ X = \lbrace f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \sum^{\infty}_{j = 1} |f(j)| < + \infty \rbrace $. We define $d_{l^1}(x_n, y_n) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |x_i - y_i|$ and $d_{l^{\infty}}(x_n, y_n) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|x_i - y_i|$.

My goal is to identify a sequence $ (f_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1} \in X$ which converges with respect to $d_{l^{\infty}}$ but doesn't converge with respect to  $d_{l^{1}}$. I also want to show that a sequence in $X$ which converges with respect to $d_{l^1}$ must also converge with respect to $d_{l^{\infty}}$.

I'm a little confused about this because my understanding is that $X$ is just the $L^p$ space with $p = 1$ and I'm struggling to understand what it means for a sequence to converge in this space under a metric other than $d_{l^1}$.

**Questions:** what does it mean for a sequence to converge with respect to the $d_{l^{\infty}}$ metric in the $L^1$ space? When would a sequence in the $L^1$ space converge with respect to $d_{l^{\infty}}$ but fail to converge with respect to $d_{l^1}$?

**EDIT:** I think I actually found a sequence that works and proved it thanks to a friendly comment. See my answer and let me know if I made any mistakes in my proof.

Comment: Okay. That’s not in $X$ since for each $n$, $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ diverges to $\infty$, right?

Comment: How do you define $d_{l^1}$? Because it is usually defined as $\sum_n |f(n)|$ as far as i know.

Comment: @A. Albano you’re right, I guess I’m not understanding how considering the sequence outside of the space I’m working in that you suggested gets me anywhere. Could you maybe say more?

Comment: Zanzag yes, that’s how I’m defining it here.

Comment: you can find an answer to your problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092015/counter-example-to-show-convergence-in-l-infty-metric-does-not-imply-the-same

Comment: Thanks! Would still love an explanation to the why behind all of this as I feel like I don’t understand the core concept of these types of convergence but I appreciate the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence in a previous answer is sufficient, but doesn't answer the other direction and I think the reasoning can be slightly more slick in this regard.

Note straight from the definitions that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty \leq \Vert \cdot \Vert_1$, the former takes a $\sup$ over the same set of values where the latter takes a sum. This implies any convergent sequence in $\ell_1$ converges in $\ell_\infty$.

This additionally means that if $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\ell_\infty$ and converges to $g$ in $\ell_1$ then $f=g$. That's because $\ell_\infty$ is a metric space, so has unique limits, and $\Vert f_n - g \Vert_\infty \leq \Vert f_n - g \Vert_1 \to 0$ i.e. $f_n$ also converges to $g$ in $\ell_\infty$.

Let $f_n = \chi_{\{m \leq n\}}\frac{1}{n}$ as in previously suggested answers. It converges to $0$ in $\ell_\infty$.

Assume that $f_n$ converges to $g$ in $\ell_1$. We must have $g=0$, but it is easy to check that $f_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $\ell_1$.

Comment: That IS slick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence in $X$ defined by

[image]

This sequence converges to the sequence $f(j) = 0$ with respect to $d_{l^{\infty}}$. This is because all non-zero terms of $f_{n}(j)$ are equal to $\frac{1}{n} > 0$. Equivalently, $\sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}|f_{n}(j)| = \frac{1}{n}$, and so
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} |f_{n}(j)| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
Now suppose there exists a function $g \in X$ to which $f_{n}(j)$ converges with respect to $d_{l^{1}}$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that when $n \geq N$, $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}|f_{n}(j) - g(j)| < \epsilon$.

For contradiction, let $\epsilon < \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |g(j)|$ and suppose $N$ satisfies the definition above. In the specific case where $n = N$, we have that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f_{n}(j) - g(j)| = |f_{N}(1) - g(1)| + \cdots + |f_{N}(N) - g(N)| + \cdots$$

$$= \Bigg|\frac{1}{N} - g(1)\Bigg| + \cdots + \Bigg|\frac{1}{N} - g(N)\Bigg| + |g(N+1)| + \cdots$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^{N}\Bigg|\frac{1}{N} - g(j) \Bigg| + \sum_{j = N+1}^{\infty}|g(j)| < \epsilon$$

Taking the limit of both sides of the inequality as $N \rightarrow \infty$, we have that
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg[\sum_{j=1}^{N}\Bigg|\frac{1}{N} - g(j) \Bigg| + \sum_{j = N+1}^{\infty}|g(j)|\Bigg] < \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|0 - g(j)| + 0 < \epsilon$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|g(j)| < \epsilon$$
This is a contradiction because we chose $\epsilon < \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|g(j)|$, and we conclude that $f_{n}(j)$ does not converge with respect to $d_{l^{1}}$.